# Pandas DataFrame manipulation and transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to import data into database using Python, but before that I need to manipulate it with pandas.
I have a csv file that I read with `reading = pd.read_csv("File.csv")` and the data looks like this:

[image: Data from csv]

I want it to look like this:

[image: Data final result]

I have tried pandas `melt()` and `pivot()` but they cut up the data in vary strange ways.
The problem is that there are like 150 countries in the headers as column names so I can't just parse them in usecols and so on.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need replace `-` to missing values, then transpose:

```
df = pd.read_csv("File.csv", na_values='-', index_col=['Date']).fillna(0).astype(int).T
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_csv("File.csv", index_col=['Date']).replace('-', 0).astype(int).T
```

Comment: A follow-up, could the dates themselves become the names of columns? Because right now I see them as the first row of dataframe and the names are 0 1 2 3 ...

Comment: @Always_stuck Can you check now?